# Problem with loading modal forms using django-fm

Tags: django, django-forms, bootstrap-modal

Based on the example given here: https://github.com/django-fm/django-fm I can not upload successfully the modal window based on the form-view-model .py appropriate file provided.

Here is my code in models.py:

```
from django.db import models

    class Test(models.Model):

        test_one = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        test_two = models.CharField(max_length=200)


        def __str__(self):
            '''this function returns the name of the instance'''
            return self.test_one+self.test_two
```

Here is my code in forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Test

class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ['test_one', 'test_two',]
```

Here is my code in views.py:

```
from fm.views import AjaxCreateView
from .forms import TestForm
from .models import Test

class TestCreateView(AjaxCreateView):

    model = Test
    form_class = TestForm
    template_name = 'form_example/test.html'
```

Here is my code in urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from form_example.views import TestCreateView


urlpatterns =[

    url(r'^create/$',TestCreateView.as_view(),name="test_create"),
]
```

and finally the code in test.html:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% include "fm/modal.html" %}
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}

        <a class="fm-create" href="{% url 'test_create' %}"  data-fm-head="Creating new User" data-fm-callback="appendWithAlert" >
         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="">Create new User</button></a> 

         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $.fm({debug: true});
            });
         </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
    $.fm({
        debug: true,
        custom_callbacks: {
            "appendWithAlert": function(data, options) {
                $(options.modal_target).append(data.message);
                alert("model instance created!");
            }
        }
    });
});
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

After pressing the "Create new User" button the outcome is:[image]

And if I comment the line

```
template_name = 'form_example/test.html'
```

in views.py and run again the app the outcome is:[image]

Ηow this strangeness is justified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i realized what went wrong.

I was trying to create the new django-fm window from the same url. Here, apart from the creation, I added the update and delete url mapping.

So, the urls.py file is defined below:

```
urlpatterns = [
#### USER CRUD ####
    url(r'^users/',views.user_list,name="users"),
    url(r'^user/new/$',views.UserCreateView.as_view(),name="user_new"),
    url(r'^user/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.UserUpdateView.as_view(), name='user_edit'),
    url(r'^user/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.UserDeleteView.as_view(), name='user_delete'),
]
```

Trying to understand how to handle django-fm forms I end up creating a whole project with AjaxCreateView, AjaxUpdateView and AjaxDeleteView operations which can be accessed from here: https://github.com/TopFlankerKiller/localagency/tree/master

Among the other information,the django-fm installation steps can be found from the user in the file : How to create and manipulate modal windows using django-fm.pdf